# Need to parse something like a GET request in python

Tags: python, string, get, split, delimiter

I've got a GET request type string the I need to parse, using python.

```
blahdeblahdeblah?query=This is the query&time=8:30
```

Does anyone know a way to extract the strings I want, such that I can do something like

```
query= This is the query
time= 8:30
```

Bear in mind that some of my strings might not have a time. So for instance

```
blahdeblahdeblah?query=This is a query without a time
```

I would need to process as well. How could I do this? I'm not sure something like splitstring would work for this, because of the option of having some variables or not.

Comment: I believe you want the `cgi` module.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse

The urllib.parse method might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `urlparse.urlparse()` ("Parse a URL into six components, returning a 6-tuple. This corresponds to the general structure of a URL: scheme://netloc/path;parameters?query#fragment.") and `urlparse.parse_qs()` ("Parse a query string given as a string argument (data of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Data are returned as a dictionary. The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values are lists of values for each name.")

```python
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs
>>> urlparse('http//www.domain.com/path?a=1&b=2')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.domain.com', path='/path', params='', query='a=1&b=2', fragment='')
>>> parse_result = urlparse('//www.domain.com/path?a=1&b=2')
>>> parse_qs(parse_result[4])
{'a': ['1'], 'b': ['2']}
```

Your example could look like:

```python
>>> for k,x in parse_qs(urlparse('blahdeblahdeblah?query=This is the query&time=8:30')[4]).items():
...     print '%s=%s' % (k, x)
...
query=['This is the query']
time=['8:30']
```

See the Python Documentation for [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) and [parse_qs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
val = 'blahdeblahdeblah?query=This is the query&time=8:30'
val = re.sub('.time=\d{1,3}\D\d{1,3}', '', val)

print val
```